# Logstash does not index when I run the service

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Here is my conf file in /etc/logstash/conf.d/apachelog.conf (Below)...I don't see index in kibana

But when i enter this command it works
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/apachelog.conf
and I see the index in elasticsearch

I want to start it when i restart my services like "service logstash start"

```
input {
file {
path => "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
type => "apache_log" # a type to identify those logs (will need this later)
start_position => "beginning"
sincedb_path => "/dev/null" #to clear since db
}
}

filter {
grok {
match=> { message => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
}
date {
locale => "en"
match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}
}

output {
#stdout { }
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
sniffing => true
manage_template => false
index => "mylogs"

}

}
```

Comment: You need to provide some more information about your environment, such as Linux version, how you installed logstash, to get started. Please update your question

Comment: You said that there is no index in kibana, but then you said you can get an index in elasticsearch, is this your issue? Or do you want an answer to "How do I run logstash as a service"?

Comment: @whites11 sudo apt-get install logstash

Comment: @WillBarnwell as a init.d service it is not running, but manually it is running and creating an index.

Comment: So, is your problem that your config doesnt work or that you can't figure out how to run it with init.d with the right config? Please edit your question and clarify what the actual problem is